# @Input() not rendering/receiving the most recent passed value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angularjs-directive

I am developing an angular application, where I am trying to pass a value from a parent component to a child component using the @Input() decorator. however, the value still renders the old/initial value from the child component and not the updated/most recently passed value from the parent component. Does anyone understand why and how to fix this?

Code:

```
@Input('amt') amount:any =100;
```

parent component

```
<app-payment [amount]="100*2"></app-payment>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The decorator name and the variable name have to match.

Change:

```
@Input('amt') amount:any =100;
```

To

```
@Input('amount') amount:any =100;
```

and that should work.

Comment: the string value inside input decorator is alias for input that will be used in template.. so if you want to have input with the same name as the property, then don't pass any value to the input decorator

Answer (score 2):

For `@Input` decorator we have optional argument `bindingPropertyName` which controls how we can bind that property in html, if no supplied it defaults to the name of property.

so, if you write

```
@Input('amt') amount:any =100;
```

You are setting `bindingPropertyName` to `amt` hence to use it in template you need to write something like.

```
<app-payment [amt]="100*2"></app-payment>
```

you can skip `bindingPropertyName` and it will use default value (name of property here `amount`) or use something else if needed.

Generally, we don't use `bindingPropertyName` but sometimes for directives we may want to avoid conflict of binding property name (as we can apply a directive to a component which may also define a property with same name and `bindingPropertyName`) so we can prefix it with directive name.